# Detecting emails in a text

Tags: php, regex, email, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to create a function that translates every occurrence of a plain text email address in a given string into it's *htmlized* version.

Let's say I have the following code, where `htmlizeEmails` is the function I'm looking for:

```
$str = "Send me an email to bob@example.com.";
echo htmlizeEmails($str); // Echoes "Send me an email to <a href="mailto:bob@example.com">bob@example.com</a>."
```

If possible, I'd like this function to use the [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function to check if the email is valid.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

#### Edit:

Thanks for the answers, I used Shocker's regex to match potential email addresses and then, **only** if the `filter_var` validates it, it gets replaced.

```
function htmlizeEmails($text)
    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/', $text, $potentialEmails, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    
    $potentialEmailsCount = count($potentialEmails);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $potentialEmailsCount; $i++) {
        if (filter_var($potentialEmails[$i][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $text = str_replace($potentialEmails[$i][0], '<a href="mailto:' . $potentialEmails[$i][0] .'">' . $potentialEmails[$i][0] .'</a>', $text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: No, I don't want customized regex, as they aren't very reliable for parsing email addresses. Is better to let `filter_var` do the job

Comment: `filter_var` uses regular expressions internally. [Comparing email regex](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php)

Comment: I added a comprehensive regular expression to my answer, see if it suits your needs ;)

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get email address from a long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028553/how-to-get-email-address-from-a-long-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/', '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

where `([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})` is the regular expression used for detecting an email address (this is a general example, email addresses may be more complicated than this and not all addresses may be covered, but finding the perfect regex for emails is up to you)

Answer (score 6):

There's always matching every sequence of non-space characters and testing those with `filter_var`, but this is probably one of those cases where it's just better to use regular expressions.

```
echo preg_replace('/(([\w!#$%&\'*+\-\/=?^`{|}~]|\\\\\\\\|\\\\?"|\\\\ )+\.)*([\w!#$%&\'*+\-\/=?^`{|}~]|\\\\\\\\|\\\\?"|\\\\ )+@((\w+[\.-])*[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])/', '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

I've tried to follow the standard as best I could without making it ridiculously compliant. And anybody who puts comments in his or her e-mail address can just be forgotten safely, I think. And it [definitely works for common e-mails](http://codepad.org/WNyXKIMb).

---

EDIT: After a long, difficult struggle, here's my regular expression to match everything:

```
((([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~]+|"([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~(),:;<>@\[\]]|\\[ \\"])+")\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~]+|"([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~(),:;<>@\[\]]|\\[ \\"])+"))@((([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*)?\.)*[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[((0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]|\[[Ii][Pp][vV]6(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){6}\]))
```

Enjoy escaping it!

Comment: Slightly improved version https://regex101.com/r/l8lTif/1 Matches all cases mentioned here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/testing123/2009/02/06/email-address-test-cases/ and also makes inner groups non-capturing to reduce noise in matches

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work fine, but it regex is easier to go with.

```
$str = "Send me an email to bob@example.com.";

   function htmlizestring($a){

        if(substr_count($a,"@") != 1){
            return false;
        }else{
            $b4 = stristr($a,"@",true);
            $b4pos = strripos($b4," ")+1;
            $b4 = trim(substr($b4,$b4pos));
            $after = stristr($a,"@");           
            if(substr_count($after, " ") == 0){
                $after=rtrim($after," .,");
            }else{
                $after=trim(stristr($after," ",true));
            }
            $email = $b4.$after;
            echo $email;
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                echo "Send me an email at: <a href='mailto:".$email."'>".$email."</a>";
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }   

    }

    htmlizestring($str);
```

I happen to use `stristr()` with the third parameter TRUE, which only works on php 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var` is nice to validate an email, but Dominic Sayers' `is_email` is even better, and my personal choice.

source code: http://code.google.com/p/isemail/source/browse/PHP/trunk/is_email.php

about: http://isemail.info/about