# php simple dom parser find email in html string

Tags: php, regex, parsing, dom, html-email

how I can find valid email through php simple dom parser in HTML String. 
thank you fou your help.

I've this code

```
 $html = $this->file_get_contents_curl('domain.com');
 $content = str_get_html($html) or die('this is not a valid url');
 $email = $content->find('a');

 foreach ($email as $k => $v) {
 if (preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $v)) 
            {
                echo  $v->href;
            }

        }
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: I think you want $v not $a for preg_match

Comment: yes exactly but did not work

Comment: **for example `foreach ($email as $k => $v) {echo $v->href}` find only links without emails :( But Email adsress are contain in the html string.**

Comment: Perhaps provide some sample data ...

Comment: I have tried this and I think perhap this work http://stackoverflow.com/a/4671694

Answer (score 0):

foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
echo $e->href . '
';

You will get all the anchor tags. Then you have to work on it.