# Extract Email address from text file

Tags: php, email, extract

I am fetching the file content like

```
$text = file_get_contents(' MY PAGE URL HERE ');
```

I want to extract the mail addresses in the page. I am using the below code spinet.

```
$res = preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",$text,$matches);
```

Normally it is working fine. but getting an issue. If the page contain a mail id like  `suren.roy@gmail.com` then it is extracting only `roy@gmail.com`. The text before the first `.` is eliminated.

Comment: You have to define the part before your dot (".") in your regex as a group so that it is put to your `$matches`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get email address from a long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028553/how-to-get-email-address-from-a-long-string)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/si',$text, $matches);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: what about something@co.uk ?

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Comment: Please can you explain your answer?