# How to separate email id from unstructured data set

Tags: php, email, dataset

How to separate email addresses from given data set and display it

> PERSONAL DETAILS NAME IN FULL JOHN DOE PERMANET ADDRESS 23B Mallwood
>   Place,  London MOBILE NUMBER 0777896546.3 FIXED NUMBER 02078585854
>   NATIONAL ID. 987456321 GENDER Male DATE OF BIRTH 1988-03-15 EMAIL
>   doe@jonshon.com ALTERNAE EMAIL JOHNDOE@HOTMAIL.COM Work related email
>   send to john.doe@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regex` to extract email address from a long text.

check [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028553/how-to-get-email-address-from-a-long-string)