# Find email address from website url

Tags: php, curl

I want to find website email address(like name@example.com) from website url link. 
 so, is it possible to find email address from website url ? 
 if yes then, please share how to implement.  
 Language is not necessary.

> as per my view, 
>   if we read content from website url using CURL, and 
>   find email address from them using regular expression.
>   is it possible ?

find bellow code for read page content from website url using CURL:

```
<?php
$url = 'yoururl';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

after then find email address using regex expression from $data string.

> **Is it possible ?**

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028553/how-to-get-email-address-from-a-long-string

Answer (score 3):

Technically you could get an email address from a domain by querying the public WHOIS information (which could be done by querying an API) but the email address publicised are rarely a companies true email address but rather reporting mailboxes for spam or technical requests.

http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=network&host=www.google.com

Some example code of how it could be done returning JSON output:

```
<?php

function getIP() {

   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
     $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
             $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return chkIP($ip);

}

function chkIP($ip) {

     $dirtydomain = gethostbyaddr($ip);
     preg_match("/((\w*)\.+(\w{2})\.+(\w{2})$)|((\w*)\.+(\w{3})$)/", $dirtydomain, $output_array);
     $cmd = 'whois ' . $output_array[0];
     $data = shell_exec($cmd);

     return getEmail($data,$output_array[0]);

}


function getEmail($data,$domain) {

    $array = preg_split('/( )|(\n)/',$data); //DATA from WHOIS

        foreach ($array as $value) {

            if (strpos($value, '@') == TRUE) {

                    $emailArray[] = $value;

            } 
        }

        return outputArray($emailArray,$domain);
}



function outputArray($emailArray, $domain) {

        if (count($emailArray) < 1) {

           return json_encode("No Email Address Found for " . $domain);

        } else {

           return json_encode($emailArray);

        }

}

getIP(); //Will Return JSON Output


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy regexp on the top of my head.

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9\.]{1,50}@[a-z0-9]{1,50}\.[a-z]{1,5})/ims",$data,$matches)
```

Comment: but is it possible to read all domian webpage using CURL ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to spider the whole domain? Thats a bit trickier task maybe something like this is the best option then: http://emailextractorpro.com/