# Return word from string containing @ php

Tags: php, string

I've been trying this for quite some time now but to no avail

I need to read a string and return the substring word that contains '@' for instance, 
there is a string like "andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com"
want the function to return substring "andrew@gomail.com"

tried explode, strpos, and substr so as to find the position of @ and then find spaces and then explode cant really get it to work 
your kind help is appreciated

Comment: first, explode by a space so you have the single words in an array. then, loop over the array and look if your word contains an at. if it does: return it. there's not more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward approach to get all such substrings:

```
$s = "andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com or man@ohman.com";
$ss = explode(" ", $s);
$res = array();
foreach($ss as $x) {
    if (strpos($x, "@") > -1) {
        array_push($res, $x);
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

See an [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/VYFKNC).

If you prefer a regex, you may match one or more non-whitespace symbols with `\S+`, and use [`\S+@\S+` regex](https://regex101.com/r/sC3qQu/1) to extract chunks of non-whitespaces + `@` + non-whitespaces (with the min length of 3):

```
$s = "andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com or man@ohman.com";
$res = array();
preg_match_all('~\S+@\S+~', $s, $res);
print_r($res);
```

to get rid of any non-word char at the end, add `\b` at the end of the regex. See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/yApTIO).

**NOTE**: To grab emails from a longer string, you may use an approach described by Rob Locke in [*How to get email address from a long string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671694/3832970) SO thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is regex.
This is PHP code for you:

```
$re = '/(?<=\b)\w([\w\.\-_0-9])*(@| at )[\w0-9][\w\-_0-9]*((\.| DOT )[\w\-_0-9]+)+(?=\b)/mi';
$str = 'andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$text_array = explode(' ', 'andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com');

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($text_array); $i++)
{
    if(strpos($text_array[$i], '@'))
    {
        array_push($result, $text_array[$i]);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep things simple :)

```
$str = "andrew garfield invited as andrew@gomail.com";
$strArr = explode('@',$str);
$pieces = explode(' ', $strArr[0]);
$last_word = array_pop($pieces);
$email =  $last_word.'@'.$strArr[1];
echo $email;
```